# How to use a program that splits a string as a variable in a for loop

Tags: c++, function, variables

This is the question: Is it possible to use a program that splits a string so that the value from that program is used as a variable inside a for loop.

Here is the program to split the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

template <class Container>
void f(const std::string& str, Container& cont)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
         std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
         std::back_inserter(cont));
}


int main()
{
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    split1(str, words);
    std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(),
         std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

And then, inside the main() program, I want to write a for loop that iterates over the value returned from the program that splits the string, and print the items in it. Similar to this:

```
int main() {

 #some statements

 //var1 should be the value returned from the program that splits the string

 for (int i = 0 ; i<=strlen(var1); i++) {
        cout << var1[i]; }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe the entire program that splits the string can be turned into a single function; and then the call of that function could be assigned to the variable `var1`; and this means that `var1` should be a string or a char array, which someway conflicts  with the type of the function that is used in this case.

Is it possible to do such kind of operations using the C++ syntax?
I've started using C++ very recently and some things seem pretty much complex.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `size()` instead of `strlen(...)`. Use `words` instead of `var1`. If this doesn't help, please clarify your question by removing unneeded stuff, and possibly providing [mcve].

Comment: `for (int i = 0 ; i<=strlen(var1); i++)` -- A `for` loop with `<=` as a condition is almost always wrong.  Also, using `strlen`-- are you using `C`-language books or material to learn C++ programming?  If so, don't.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was just an idea that I had and I wanted to ask someone if it is possible theoretically. If I search and find out that it is, I will share my thoughts about this.

Comment: Thanks! I know that this type of iteration is valid, though. I've heard that C++ is a very  powerful language, but after all, everyone started somehow.

Comment: Are there any best practices for C++, like guides on how to correctly write code? Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to clarify the answer to this question because the form of iteration that generally works for strings or char arrays, could not be used here.

I fixed the code by using iteration with indices, over an std::vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template <class Container>
void split1(const std::string& str, Container& cont)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
         std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
         std::back_inserter(cont));
}


int main()
{
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    split1(str, words);
    std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(),
         std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

    cout << "\n";

    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != words.size(); i++){

        cout << words[i] << " "; }

}
```

After executing the code:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog                                                                                                   
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The function `strlen()` and the variable `var1` had to be replaced with `size()` and the variable `words`. In addition to this, the condition in the for loop had to be replaced in order to be suitable for iteration over an std::vector.